# Difference between de-novo async function vs conversion of a simple synchronous function with a Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

In order to minimize code duplication, I've written some simple JS/TS async functions by encapsulating the respective synchronous function within a Promise. But, not seeing this elsewhere, I'm concerned that I may be missing some design problem(s).

For example:

```js
function fileExistsSync(path: string) {
    try {
        const result = Deno.statSync(path);
        return result.isFile;
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Deno.errors.PermissionDenied) {
            throw err;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

async function fileExists(path: string) {
    return await Promise.resolve().then(() => fileExistsSync(path));
}

async function fileExistsAsync(path: string) {
    try {
        const result = await Deno.stat(path);
        return result.isFile;
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Deno.errors.PermissionDenied) {
            throw err;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any observable difference between the functions `fileExists()` and `fileExistsAsync()`?

Comment: Uh, `fileExistsSync` blocks and will not allow concurrency? This is not a subtle problem. Do not wrap synchronous operations in promise-returning functions!

Comment: `return await Promise.resolve().then(() => fileExistsSync(path));` could be simplified to `return fileExistsSync(path);`. The promise stuff gains nothing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*In order to minimize code duplication*". Do you mean that you need both `fileExistsAsync` and `fileExistsSync` in your project? And want to simplify the asynchronous implementation by making it synchronous?

Comment: @Bergi , I was under the impression that `.then(...)` was executed on a future event loop tick, avoiding blocking sync code.

Comment: Yes, it's not blocking *now* because you deferred the execution, but it will still block the event loop with synchronous code on that (very long) future tick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because `fileExists` uses `Deno.statSync` where `fileExistsAsync` uses `Deno.stat`.

The sync versions of IO functions block the entire JS execution runtime, while the promise/async `Deno.stat` version allows other JS code to continue to execute while waiting for a result.

Comment: ah, `block the entire JS execution runtime`, so, b/c of `Deno.statSync()`, moving the code to a later event tick with `.then(...)` just causes a sync block at some later time.

Comment: That's right, @rivy. It's not even a tick later since we're then-ing a promise.resolve.

Comment: Strongly recommend checking out some explanations of the event loop, especially looking at how promises schedule their work ie. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en